# Default to Always Unique for unregistered concrete types

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap, structuremap3

Consider this code

```
var container = new Container();
var nested = container.GetNestedContainer();

var f1 = nested.GetInstance<Foo>();
var f2 = nested.GetInstance<Foo>();

var result = f1 == f2; //I want result to be false
```

I don't want to register each concrete type that can be injected but I want them all to be unique for each constructor injection or call to `GetInstance`

**Update:**

Hmm, I must be using NestedContainers wrong? What I want to do is to create a "Sub"-container for a sub part of the program (Its a WPF Client so a sub part could be a Sub model like a popup or whatever). The sub model can have its own sub model(s) or service(s), they can either be Concrete and not registered or interfaced that are registered. The concrete types I don't want to register at all. And the interfaces I want to default to what Structuremap called AlwaysUnique, but in my world that is just what transient lifetime is. For 99.9% of my types I want AlwaysUnique and 0.01% I want same reference during the life time of the Nested Container. Maybe this use case it not correct for Nested containers?

**Edit:** A typical use case for this is event aggregation only in a part of the program like a popup model and its children

Answer (score 1):

In case I understand your issue correctly, we can just specify the **`ILifecycle`** explitily - to be transient *(re-created every time requested)*: **`TransientLifecycle`**

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For<IMyService>(new StructureMap.Pipeline.TransientLifecycle())
     .Use<MyService>();
});
```

and that would resolve in this

```
var f1 = container.GetInstance<IMyService>();
var f2 = container.GetInstance<IMyService>();

Assert.IsTrue(f1 != f2);
```

Almost the same could be achieved with our custom convention:

```
public class MyConvention : DefaultConventionScanner
{
    public override void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        base.Process(type, registry);

        // here we shold do some evaluation what to map
        // for example
        // just classes wich are not abstract 
        var skipType = type.IsAbstract
                       || !type.IsClass;
        if (skipType)
        {
            return;
        }

        // here we do the magic
        // register each type with transient Lifecycle
        registry.For(type)
            .LifecycleIs(new StructureMap.Pipeline.TransientLifecycle())
            .Use(type);
    }
}
```

And this could be used like this to get the same results

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.Scan(s =>
    {
        s.AssemblyContainingType<MyService>();
        s.Convention<MyConvention>();
    });
}

var f1 = container.GetInstance<MyService>();
var f2 = container.GetInstance<MyService>();

Assert.IsTrue(f1 != f2);
```

Comment: Transient lifetime is not really transient in a nested container.  But your answer gave me some ideas, let me test some and get back